# Can I set a variable that will change the floatfield when using cout?

Tags: c++, cout, scientific-notation, iomanip

I want to be able to easily change the floatfield from scientific to fixed dependent on a condition, so my result would change from something like 3.000000e+00 to 3.0, using code that might look something like this:

```
some_datatype floatfield;
float number = 5.894
if (condition) {
    floatfield = 'scientific';
} else floatfield = 'fixed';
cout << "hello" << floatfield << number << endl;
```

I'm aware I can achieve the same effect using

```
float number = 5.894
if (condition) {
    cout << "hello" << scientific << number << endl;
} else cout << "hello" << fixed << number << endl;
```

But this does not generalise well if I start using more stream format flags.

If `some_datatype` exists, what is it? If not, is there any other way of changing the stream format flags using a condition?

Comment: First (among many) questions - what is `some_datatype`?

Comment: That is part of the question - I have no idea what it would be, if it were to exist. Question edited to include this

Comment: `some_datatype` (`std::ios_base::fmtflags`) would be [implementation specific](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/fmtflags). I don't understand what you're expecting to see when you write `cout << floatfield` though, that would print the value of `floatfield` if possible, not adjust cout formatting in any way...

Comment: What's unclear about this? Come on guys.

Comment: [Here's the answer.](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fe99371051eb2eb) Would have posted it as such had the question not been closed. :( Ping me if it gets re-opened and I'll fix it

Comment: @Romen [It need not be implementation specific at all.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) And the end result you describe is literally the point of the question.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Harder now when they changed the voting limits again. :)

Comment: Yay, finally :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I/O manipulators are actually functions (!), and the ones you want to switch between happen to have the same signature.

So, you can use a function pointer to achieve your goal:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using ManipFuncType = std::ios_base&(std::ios_base&);
    const bool condition = true; // or false!

    ManipFuncType* floatfield;
    float number = 5.894;
    if (condition)
        floatfield = std::scientific;
    else
        floatfield = std::fixed;

    std::cout << "hello" << floatfield << number << std::endl;
}
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d161fc53c1fe0ecc))

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood the question correctly, but this could be a solution:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct my_float {
    float value_;
    bool scientific_ = true;
    my_float(float value) : value_(value) {}
    void set_scientific() { scientific_ = true; }
    void set_fixed() { scientific_ = false; }
};
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const my_float& f) {
    if (f.scientific_)
        return os << scientific << f.value_;
    else
        return os << fixed << f.value_;
}

int main() {
    my_float number = 5.894;
    bool condition = true; // <--- Change this!
    if (condition) {
        number.set_scientific();
    }
    else {
        number.set_fixed();
    }
    cout << "hello" << number << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is of course very crude, and the class could definitely be more complete.

Don't use this to store many floats, because id may easily double your memory requirements.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. A better answer was posted in a comment on the question by @LightnessRacesinOrbit - this was what I was looking for!